# Can' t delete image from Firebase Storage REACT 2022

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have this code from firebase documentation on my firebase file

```
export async function deleteImage(docId){
  // Create a reference to the file to delete
const desertRef = ref(storage, `images/${docId}`);

await deleteObject(desertRef).then(() => {
  swal("GOOD",  "success");

}).catch((error) => {
  swal("error!", "error");});
}
```

➡️ And i have this code for upload and download URL image on my Dashboard View

```
async function handleOnChangeProfileImage(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    setLoading(true) // Setloading to true
    var fileList = e.target.files;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    if (fileReader && fileList && fileList.length > 0) {
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileList[0]);
      fileReader.onload = async function () {
        var imageData = fileReader.result;

        const res = await setUserProfilePhoto(currentUser.uid, imageData);

        if (res) {
          const tmpUser = { ...currentUser };
          tmpUser.profilePicture = res.metadata.fullPath;
          setCurrentUser({ ...tmpUser });
          await updateUser(tmpUser);
          const url = await getProfilePhotoUrl(currentUser.profilePicture);
          setProfileUrl(url);
          //updateUserProfilePhoto(currentUser.uid, res.fullPath);
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

➡️ And this is in html

```
<img className="mb-3 lazyload" key={profileUrl} srcSet={profileUrl} data-src={userImg}
      width={200} alt="web.app" /> 
 
    <Button onClick={handleOpenFilePicker} variant="primary"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUpload} /> Upload</Button>

    <Button onClick={deleteImage} variant="danger"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDeleteLeft}/> Delete</Button>
```

I can upload an image successfully, but i want to delete the user's profile image with a OnClick event, and for that I use his docId as a reference, but the result is negative, what else do I have to create or do to delete the uploaded image? Hope you help me!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your `deleteImage` function expects a `docId` parameter, but you're not passing any value when invoking it here `<Button onClick={deleteImage}`.

Comment: And how am I supposed to pass it to the button or the dashboard view? Sorry but I'm pretty new to react!!

Comment: `<Button onClick={deleteImage('your document id here')}`

Comment: Well perfect, but, it does not help me that to delete a photo I have to manually enter the photo's id number, the idea is that it be more dynamic and each user can delete their photo by taking the user's data. I'm trying but I can't, it overwhelms me.

Comment: Something like this <Button onClick={() => deleteImage(currentUser.profilePicture)} -
I want the function to take the data from the profile picture parameter so that it can be deleted dynamically, but it doesn't work.

Comment: So can you also set the document ID in such a parameter then, and render it into your UI? It really helps if you can isolate your problem, as I think your problem is closer to [how to pass a parameter to a react event handler](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+pass+a+parameter+to+a+reactjs+event+handler) now.

Comment: Yes, I have access to the parameters, but it is still very confusing for me, that's why I leave the complete code so that they can help me or teach me how to do it.

Comment: I was able to solve it! Thank you very much for your help! But now my problem is that when I upload or delete the image, it does not update instantly, but I have to restart the page completely to see the changes, what is the reason for this? Should I add any more variable to the function created in firebase? Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear that you solved the original problem. That sounds like a new problem though, so I recommend opening a new question for it. I'd also recommend looking at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (again), as following the guidance in there really helps preventing long comment chains like we have here, without having answer (which is what would make this much more useful to folks who find this in the future).